# Can't interact with view out of frame

Tags: objective-c, uiview, xcode4.2

I have a little `UIVIew` which is out of the current main view, and I use this code to show it:

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone 
                 animations:^{
                            // menuView.center = CGPointMake(menuView.center.x+213,   menuView.center.y);
                            self.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x+215,   self.view.center.y);
                            } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){

                 }];
```

And the problem is I can't interact with this view. I have few button on it and they are not clickable... what is the problem?

Comment: So your view is successfully shown but you can't click buttons on it?

Comment: Exactly. I even has UIImageView which loads an image from the server and it's ok, just the button are not click able. If I take this view and put it in the middle of the screen and compile again, the buttons are ok.

Comment: It's not clickable when moving or always not clickable?

Comment: This view is not shown till the user clicks a button. It moves from left to right. Its x location is out of the screen and then it comes to the center of the screen.

Comment: Your `self.view` is not visible. Where is your button that you click to show your `self.view`?

Comment: Yes it's visible. The button is located on this view... And when moving the main view, it moves the menuView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19934/discussion-between-sunkehappy-and-yosi-dahan)

Answer (score 0):

The Core Animation takes a 'snapshot' of the view and manipulates with a single image, allowing graphic card acceleration. If you want to interact with the view, while it's moving, you'll probably need to make your own animation using a timer and slowly moving the view. It will be CPU-intensive as all the computation will be done by the CPU and not GPU.